# How to add "instagram" to share website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using js-socials plugin for share the website in social media but i need add "instagram" to this but that plugin not given any option to that so how should i can add "instagram" option without this plugin or any otherway to add.

This is my code:

```
$("#share").jsSocials({
        url: "http://curatingsimplicityqa.azurewebsites.net",
        text: "Google Search Page",
        showLabel: false,
        showCount: false,
        shares: ["twitter", "facebook", "pinterest", "linkedin"]
    });
```

And this is my plugin:

```
<script src="~/JS/jssocials.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can i add "Instagram" share buttion using any other plugin or any other way to implement

Answer (score 1):

so, actually the Instagram API doesn't have the option to share media. 
Since December 11th on 2018 Facebook change the documentation and to many things in but still not be available this option because the Instagram concept is be a social network for your life and not a business app like facebook.

Here the new documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/